# Is it possible to select an element in array with the query select and his index?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

There is a Schema :

```
{model.js}

var someSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    a : [Number],
    b : String,
    c : [Number],
    d : Number
});
```

I try to *find()* each documents and select only an element from a, element from c with same index and b.

That's what I tried :

```
{get.js}

var some = require('model');
some.find() // find
    .limit(3) // limit for 3 docs (test part)
                            // NEXT LINE IS NOT WORKING
    .select('a.0 b c.0 -d') // select {array: a and b, index:0}, b less d
    .exec(function(err, dataList) {
        if (err) {
            console.warn(err);
            return ;
        }
        console.log(data[0].a); // Show in console array a
        console.log(data[0].b); // String b
        console.log(data[0].c); // array c
                                // not select d, so d = undefined
    });
```

In this part of code, I would be able to select such an index of an array but when I tried this code, my array is selected but with no element inside.

Is there a way to select an index of an array from a schema ?

Comment: My array is `"rank": [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]` and query is `.select('rank')` but when I try `.select('rank.0')`, my array return as `"rank": []`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want [`$slice`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/) here instead:

```js
some.find()
    .limit(3)
    .select({ 
        "a": { "$slice": 1 },
        "b": 1,
        "c": { "$slice": 1 }
    })
    .exec(function(err,dataList) {
```

For just the first element all you need is the number to return, or otherwise by indexed position and then the number to return. So for the second index it would be:

```js
some.find()
    .limit(3)
    .select({ 
        "a": { "$slice": [1,1] },
        "b": 1,
        "c": { "$slice": [1,1] }
    })
    .exec(function(err,dataList) {
```

This requires the "full object" form of projection to be supplied to the `.select()` statement, or otherwise provided as the projection argument to `.find()`.

Also note that projections are either "wholly" inclusion lists or "exclusion" only. You cannot "mix" both inclusion or exclusion

Comment: That's what I meant ! I tried as .select('rank').slice(1) but didn't work for me :'(
$slice works fine, thank you master !